# Nginx on Docker (Connection Refused while connecting to upstream)

Tags: docker, nginx

I keep getting this error when I try to connect to my reverse proxy:

> 2022/09/20 01:06:43 [error] 25#25: *5 connect() failed (111:
> Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x,
> server: localhost, request: "GET /sdr_user HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "http://127.0.0.1:59524/values", host: "localhost:9191"
>
> 2022/09/20 01:06:43 [warn] 25#25: *5 upstream server temporarily
> disabled while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server:
> localhost, request: "GET /sdr_user HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "http://127.0.0.1:59524/values", host: "localhost:9191"
>
> 2022/09/20 01:06:43 [error] 25#25: *5 connect() failed (111:
> Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x,
> server: localhost, request: "GET /sdr_user HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "http://127.0.0.1:59524/values", host: "localhost:9191"
>
> 2022/09/20 01:06:43 [warn] 25#25: *5 upstream server temporarily
> disabled while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server:
> localhost, request: "GET /sdr_user HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "http://127.0.0.1:59524/values", host: "localhost:9191"

I have tried searching and it said to define my upstream server which i already have in my default.conf file like this:

```
upstream api_server {
    server localhost:59524;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;

    location /sdr_user{
        proxy_pass http://api_server/values;
    }
}
```

My reverse proxy is located in another container separate from my other projects. However, when I directly access localhost:59524, i can access the link without any issues.

Am I missing another configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localhost` has no meaning when you work with containers.

If you have a docker-compose.yml with 2 services: nginx and the application, then your nginx sees the application by the name of the service defined in docker-compose.yml

Example:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  svc1:
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    volumes:
    - "./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro"

  svc2:
    image: <some app>
```

(no need to expose ports for svc2)

Your `default.conf` should look like:

```
upstream api_server {
    server svc2:59524;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;

    location /sdr_user{
        proxy_pass http://api_server/values;
    }
}
```

(assuming your app is running on port 59524 inside the container)

Comment: My svc2 is actually called sdr_user and is located in another project called sdr_core. When I go into sdr_user on docker, its name is sdr_core_sdr_user.api_1. I have replaced svc2 with that. However, I get this error now: 2022/09/20 02:41:03 [error] 24#24: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /sdr_user HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.4:59524/values", host: "localhost:9191"

Comment: that's wrong. Your sdr_user needs to have an exposed port mapped on the host (say 59524). Next you need the network IP of the host (something like 192.168.X.X). These are the IP:port combination that you need to use.

Comment: I tried docker inspect <container_id> and then saw the ip address 172.x.x.x. I then copied that 172 ip address and put it in default.conf like this: server 172.x.x.x. However, I restarted the container then the ip address changed. Is there a way to not use ip?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to solve it by placing the name of the container without the project instead of IP.